# CASE in WHERE clause in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, parameters

Trying to use `CASE` for conditional parameter

I've already posted this before; but since I couldn't achieve the correct result, posting it again with different approach.

I have a complex code, where I only added a few elements, highlighted in yellow

My goal is:

- When @Depreciation = 0
  Need to display the values - without "Depreciation" (where DepreciationAcc =0)
- When @Depreciation = 1
  Need to display the values - with "Depreciation" (where DepreciationAcc is both 0 OR 1)

It works, but selects incorrect number of rows.

This is the part where I use CASE within WHERE:

```
 WHERE ( 
  (CASE WHEN (NOT (acct.[GLAccountCode] IN (N'9040',N'9047',N'4130')) AND 
  (@Depreciation = 0))THEN 0 ELSE trans.Amount END)=0 .............
```

Below is the full code. Part I am trying to modify - marked with /****/: (Mainly after the first WHERE)

```
DECLARE @FYMonthBOP date = '2017-07-01'
DECLARE @FYMonthEOP date = '2018-03-31'
DECLARE @GLProgramGroupsWHID int = -1
DECLARE @GLProgramsWHID_Groups int = -1
DECLARE @GLProgramGroupSetsWHID int = -1
DECLARE @Depreciation bit = 1          /****/

SELECT        
  gl0.GLGroupLevel0Name
, gl0.Ordinal AS Ordinal0
, [Dimension].GLGroupLevel1.GLGroupLevel1Name
, [Dimension].GLGroupLevel1.Ordinal AS Ordinal1
, gl2.GLGroupLevel2Name
, gl2.Ordinal AS Ordinal2
, acct.GLAccountCode
, acct.GLAccountName
         , pgm.GLProgramCode + N' ' + pgm.GLProgramName AS Program
, setname.[WHID] AS [WHIDGroupSetName]
         , grp.GroupName 
, grp.WHID AS WHIDGroupName
, grp.Ordinal AS OrdinalGroupName
, d.FYQuarterLabel AS FQ
 -- , trans.Amount AS Amount
 -- , CASE WHEN     ((acct.[GLAccountCode] IN (N'9040',N'9047',N'4130')) 
  AND (@Depreciation = 0)) THEN 0 ELSE trans.Amount END AS [Amount] 
, pgm.[WHID] AS WHIDProgram
, pgm.Ordinal AS OrdinalProgram
, d.FYMonthNumber
, d.FYMonthShortLabel
, d.FYQuarterNumber
, d.FYNumber
, d.FYLabel
, d.YearMonthSort
, IIF(EOMonth(mm.DateThru) < @FYMonthEOP, EOMonth(mm.DateThru), 
       @FYMonthEOP) AS [DateThru]
, IIF((acct.[GLAccountCode]) IN (N'9040',N'9047',N'4130'), 1, 0) AS 
      [DepreciationAcct]

 FROM            
(([Dimension].GLGroupLevel2 gl2 WITH (NoLock)
INNER JOIN [Dimension].GLAccount acct WITH (NoLock) ON gl2.[WHID] = 
                                     acct.GLGroupLevel2FK 
INNER JOIN [Dimension].GLGroupLevel0 gl0 WITH (NoLock)
INNER JOIN [Dimension].GLGroupLevel1 WITH (NoLock) ON gl0.[WHID] = 
               [Dimension].GLGroupLevel1.GLGroupLevel0FK ON    
               GLGroupLevel1FK = [Dimension].GLGroupLevel1.[WHID] 
INNER JOIN Fact.GLTransactionsMonthly trans WITH (NoLock) ON acct. 
                   [WHID] = trans.GLAccountFK 
INNER JOIN [Dimension].GLProgram pgm WITH (NoLock) ON trans. 
               [GLProgramFK] = pgm.[WHID] AND trans.[GLProgramFK] = 
               pgm.[WHID] AND trans.[GLProgramFK] = pgm.[WHID] 
INNER JOIN [Dimension].[Date] d WITH (NoLock) ON trans.EffectiveMonth = 
               d.[Date] AND trans.EffectiveMonth = d.[Date] 

                AND trans.EffectiveMonth = d.[Date] 
INNER JOIN [Reports].GLProgramGroupMapping map ON map.GLProgramFK = 
                         pgm.[WHID]
INNER JOIN [Reports].GLProgramGroup grp ON grp.WHID = 
                         map.GLProgramGroupFK
INNER JOIN [Reports].GLProgramGroupSet setname ON setname.WHID = 
                         grp.GLProgramGroupSetFK))

CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT MAX(t.EffectiveMonth) AS [DateThru] 
    FROM Fact.GLTransactionsMonthly t WITH (NoLock) 
) mm

  WHERE ( 
     (CASE WHEN (NOT (acct.[GLAccountCode] IN (N'9040',N'9047',N'4130')) 
                 AND (@Depreciation = 0)) 
            THEN 0 ELSE trans.Amount END)=0 AND    /****/

     (trans.EffectiveMonth BETWEEN @FYMonthBOP AND @FYMonthEOP)
AND ((setname.WHID IN (@GLProgramGroupSetsWHID)) OR (-1 IN 
         (@GLProgramGroupSetsWHID)))
AND ((grp.WHID IN (@GLProgramGroupsWHID)) OR (-1 IN 
         (@GLProgramGroupsWHID)))
AND ((pgm.[WHID] IN (@GLProgramsWHID_Groups)) OR (-1 IN 
         (@GLProgramsWHID_Groups)))

AND (
    (pgm.[WHID] IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT      
         f.[GLProgramFK]

    FROM            
        Fact.GLTransactionsMonthly f
        INNER JOIN [Dimension].[GLAccount] acct ON f. 
                    [GLAccountFK] = acct.[WHID]

    WHERE 
        (f.EffectiveMonth BETWEEN @FYMonthBOP AND @FYMonthEOP)
        AND (acct.[GLAccountCode] BETWEEN '5000' AND '9999')

    GROUP BY
         f.[GLProgramFK]

    HAVING 
        (SUM(f.[Amount]) <> 0))
    )
OR
    (pgm.[WHID] IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT      
         f.[GLProgramFK]

    FROM            
        Fact.GLTransactionsMonthly f
        INNER JOIN [Dimension].[GLAccount] acct ON f. 
                    [GLAccountFK] = acct.[WHID]

    WHERE 
        (f.EffectiveMonth BETWEEN @FYMonthBOP AND @FYMonthEOP)
        AND (acct.[GLAccountCode] BETWEEN '4000' AND '4999')

    GROUP BY
         f.[GLProgramFK]

    HAVING 
        (SUM(f.[Amount]) <> 0))
    )
OR 
    (pgm.[GLProgramCode] IN ('549'))

)   
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Just recently learned about the right approach on this my problem -

```
CASE WHEN   (acct.[GLAccountCode] IN (N'9040',N'9047',N'4130')) AND 
            (@Depreciation = 0) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)=1
```

No need to include trans.Amount field, and the value has to be **equal 1**, not 0
That way it'll show all values

Answer (score 0):

Consider the basic structure of your predicate:

```
(CASE 
    WHEN ... AND @Depreciation = 0 THEN 0 
    ELSE trans.Amount END 
) = 0
```

**Everything** coming out of the case expression is evaluated by the **equal 0** so if `trans.Amount <> 0` then it will not survive into the result

**EDIT**

I think you might want this:

```
WHERE ( 
         (@Depreciation = 0 and  [DepreciationAcct] = 0)
       OR
         (@Depreciation = 1 and  [DepreciationAcct] IN (0,1))
      )
```

Comment: Yes, you're correct - I just noticed and checked - about what you mentioned -
When Depreciation = 1 it shows ONLY the rows where trans.Amount = 0 (1935 rows)

My question is -  HOW do I show all the rest values for @Depreciation = 1?

Comment: Well, perhaps you could re-think how to ask technical questions. Instead of re-listing a longish query that does not match your needs as your question, you could supply a tiny example of the data (called "sample data") and the result you want from that data (called "expected result"). This is known here at stackoverflow as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and there are great reasons for using these, see [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: In addition to this, it seems to me that you may not need any of that logic in the where clause, instead you may just need it in the select clause, but to be honest I just do not really understand what you really want (the question is unclear).

Comment: @ Used_By_Already, Sorry and Thank you, I'll make edits

What I want (my goal) is the following:
When Depreciation = 0, I want to see the rows ONLY where the field [DepreciationAcct]  = 0 (this is the field from my IIF statement in the code above)

When Depreciation = 1 I want to see the rows where [DepreciationAcct] = 1 or
[DepreciationAcct] = 0 - both of these values

Comment: @ Used_By_Already
Thank you, but ... unfortunately the field [DepreciationAcct] is part of the following IIF statement -

IIF((acct.[GLAccountCode]) IN (N'9040',N'9047',N'4130'), 1, 0) AS [DepreciationAcct]  
and can't be used as independent part of the condition.
My warehouse simply doesn't recognize it

Comment: Did you know you can edit your question? Have you provided sample data? Have you provided expected results? I have not noticed any extra information that would be useful to help solve your problem.